# WindowManager added views count

Tags: android, window-managers

I'm making some Service. This Service have to add some overlay views on the screen, when the device starts.
I'm adding views using WindowManager, like this

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    SomeView ll;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams ll_lp;

    <some code>

    wm.addView(ll, ll_lp);
```

Everything is working good until those views ain't disappear somehow. 
I didn't catch the reason why and when those views disappear.
But the way I thought I could fix this problem is to recreate this views from time to time.

But I faced with the next problem - I just can't get added views from WindowManager. I can see them in the debugger window, but I can't get any access to those views from my code. All I need - it's not even an access to every view but just a current count of added views in WindowManager. 
Any idea how to get this count?

Comment: maybe store references to your views in your service?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Do you meen that if I have

  SomeView ll;

than I have to store "ll" somehow? 
Can you tell me please how can I do that?

Comment: you can store it as a service member variable, before recreating it  you can call `removeView` to remove it from window manager.

Comment: Oh, I see.
Unfortunately I've already thought about it. 
The problem is that when `BroadcastReceiver` again comes into `onReceive` method then all member variables have `null` value. So I just don't know which view I have to remove.

Comment: so you have service and broadcastreceiver?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have BroadcastReceiver, which catches BOOT_COMPLETED action and then it starts Service.

Oh, I think I understand what I did wrong, thank you! 
I'll check it and I will tell is it helps me or not.